# apt packages are missing from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

Ubuntu 16.04 installed updates some weeks before and changed the Ubuntu Software app in the way that only snap package apps are shown.
No other software is available.

[image: New Ubuntu Software]

Can it be changed back to the way it was before?

Comment: Does `apt` work?  E.g. does `apt-cache search .` list all available packages?  If not, that suggests a problem with your apt setup.  Also, the config file for ubuntu software is in `~/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg`; you could look there for a strange setting, or simply `rm ~/.config/software-center/*` to reset to the default.

Comment: apt work fine, apt-get also. I have installed the old Software-Center - works fine and Synaptik works too. In ".config" is no /software-center/